# Tailwind: respect dynamic height when using whitespace-pre-line utility?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use `whitespace-pre-line` to show multiline strings, although it is not respecting the height of what it requires, instead it messes up the alignment of any items following it?

I've created a playground example:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/s3ZMXnUihZ?layout=horizontal

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding `overflow-auto` helper class for (`overflow: auto;`) css rule to the parent (`p`) tag of the span.